# CTE with DELETE - Alternative for SQL Data Warehouse

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database, common-table-expression, sql-delete, azure-synapse

I would like to delete all rows in a table where the batchId (a running number) older than the previous two. I could probably do this in a SQL Database with the query:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT
        *,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY BATCHID DESC) AS RN
    FROM MyTable
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN>2
```

But the same is not allowed in a SQL Data Warehouse per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#features-and-limitations-of-common-table-expressions-in--and-). Looking for alternatives here.

Comment: Does `MyTable` have a primary key which could be used?

Comment: It does not, but I can always add an identity column

Comment: It may help for deleting without the CTE by using a `ID NOT IN` select which finds the row to delete as subquery. Haven't used azure-sql-data-warehouse through so I don't know if that would actually help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using JOIN

```
delete d from MyTable d
join 
(
 SELECT
        *,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY BATCH_ID ORDER BY BATCH_ID DESC)
    FROM MyTable
)A on d.batch_id=A.batch_id where RN >2
```

Comment: A FROM clause is currently not supported in a DELETE statement. getting same issue

Answer (score 1):

Azure SQL Data Warehouse only supports a limited T-SQL surface area and CTEs for `DELETE` operations and `DELETEs` with `FROM` clauses which will yield the following error:

> Msg 100029, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   A FROM clause is currently not supported in a DELETE statement.

It does however support sub-queries so one way to write your statement like this:

```
DELETE dbo.MyTable
WHERE BATCHID Not In ( SELECT TOP 2 BATCHID FROM dbo.MyTable ORDER BY BATCHID DESC );
```

This syntax is supported in Azure SQL Data Warehouse and I have tested it.  I'm not sure how efficient it will be on billions of rows though.  You could also consider partition switching.

If you are deleting a large portion of your table then it might make sense to use a CTAS to put the data you want to keep into a new table, eg something like this:

```
-- Keep the most recent two BATCHIDS
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable2
WITH
(
    CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX,
    DISTRIBUTION = HASH( BATCHID )
    -- Add partition scheme here if required
)
AS
SELECT  *
FROM dbo.MyTable
WHERE BATCHID In ( SELECT TOP 2 BATCHID FROM dbo.MyTable ORDER BY BATCHID DESC )
OPTION ( LABEL = 'CTAS : Keep top two BATCHIDs' );
GO

-- Rename or DROP old table
RENAME OBJECT dbo.MyTable TO MyTable_Old;
RENAME OBJECT dbo.MyTable2 TO MyTable;
GO

-- Optionally DROP MyTable_Old if everything has been successful
-- DROP TABLE MyTable_Old
```

This technique is described in more detail [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-develop-best-practices-transactions#optimizing-deletes).

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
delete t from mytable t
    where batchId < (select max(batchid) from mytable);
```

Oh, if you want to keep two, perhaps this will work:

```
delete t from mytable t
    where batchId < (select batchid
                     from mytable
                     group by batchid
                     limit 1 offset 1
                    );
```

Comment: I don't see how this condition can match any row? Can you elaborate?

Comment: I do have this as a temporary solution, but this does not solve what I need. I need the past 2 batchids to be retained in the table.There could be gaps in the batch Id though each batch id is greater than the previous.